# WordPress stripping away backslash after file upload

Tags: wordpress

I'm not sure how to re-phrase this question. I have tried googling this issue and haven't found any solutions.

I have a WordPress server(HTTPS) through which I run some HTML pages. Now I use the Wp file-manager to upload file that are to run internally.

For some reason, when uploading any `*.js` file, certain characters in the file  are removed after upload. Especially the next line code `\n` gets converted to `n`. Due to this the result generated by the code is messed up.

This also extends to HTML files with some script in them..

For a workaround, I paste the code in a notepad file and save it as the required `.js` file and then upload it. Also I'm using `\\`, so that one of them gets stripped away and retains one hence retaining the original code.  This is when it works. Don't know why is this. Any suggestions or solutions?

I use sublime text to write my code and make sure the encoding is UTF-8 when saving the file.

Comment: Wait, are you saying you're using the WP media library to upload scripts?

Comment: Purpose of WP media manager is to save static files like images, documents etc. For any executable files like the one you are trying to upload which you intend to RUN internally as you said, you need to upload via FTP or Server control panel, WP media manager is not file manager but just media manager for static files...

Comment: Its through the Server Control panel. I use the file manager from the control panel and upload the script files.